# React native expected a string or class function but got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error:
builded with expo
Trouble in import  containers to main file app.js

SignIn code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm';
export default class SignIn extends Component {
  render() {
        return (
            <View>
               <Text>
               </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import SignIn from './app/containers';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Ma App
        </Text>

         <SignIn />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

if I remove signIn it's work!

Error on screen[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the path to your `SignIn` component is incorrect, or you are missing the `index.js` export.  You can test this theory by console logging the component `SignIn`; you will find it prints `undefined`.

The reason is you are attempting to import a default module `SignIn` from path `./app/containers`. Assuming that is a valid path, you are attempting to import the default export from `./app/containers/index.js`. This is unlikely to be correct as the `index.js` (AKA barrel) purpose is to export multiple public modules from an app directory.

Assuming your `index.js` is defined correctly, and includes the following or similar.

```
export { default as SignIn } from './SignIn.js';
```

Then you should update your import of `SignIn` to import a named module instead of the default module; as follows.

```
import { SignIn} from './app/containers';
```

Alternatively, you could import the default module direct from the component's source file.

```
import SignIn from './app/containers/SignIn';
```

Hope this helps!